# Unity2D Simulating height with Top Down Shadows

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, shadow, topdown

So the problem is the following:
I have been trying to make this flying simulator little phone game, the problem is i cant make the shadow change with a smooth transition...

[image: Image Before the cloud]

[image: Image in the cloud]

That White squared is a cloud, and the objective is to have the shadow change size while in the cloud...
I don´t really know were to start, i tried shaders, but i´m not that good with that...
Thx :))

Comment: The simpelst way I could think of is having the cloud nearer the plane so the shadow looks bigger? Other way would be to not use a shadow but a sprite which you move parallel to the plane so it does look like a shadow even though its a game object.

Comment: Thank you for your input! The shadow is already a sprite, im not using any lights in this project

Comment: You are welcome. If you need more ideas dont hesetate to ask.

Comment: Without thinking too much i'd probably have a second shadow that changes size (the one on the clouds). The sea/ground one can stay there. Before you hit a cloud you resize the shadow to the appropriate size. Now that shadow needs a shader that only renders on top of the cloud. You can use something like the stencil buffer to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not into shaders, I would look into Masks. Masks basically limit a sprite to only draw within it's boundaries.

In this example, you could have a mask on the cloud. To make it work, have the "nearer" shadow be always drawn, but only in the mask's boundaries (In this case - the cloud) [Relevant Youtube Tutorial](https://youtu.be/4pl8DcsCQ_k)